# iOS openURL to another app

Tags: iphone, ios, openurl

Can I **disable app to app default iOS animation**? I am thinking this is not possible, just

seeking confirmation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many tweaks in Cydia do that - it's certainly possible.

Comment: If you're jailbroken, this is possible as H2CO3 stated in the comments. However, if you aren't jailbroken, there is no way to disable this animation.

Comment: thank you for confirmation.